# Loop through an array of objects and check it's properties

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic2

I have an array of objects assigned to in_timings variable. I want to check certain conditions on the objects so as to prepare for some execution. 
I don't know what I'am doing wrong but the loop seems to execute on blocks I didn't expect it to.

```
in_timings:TimeInModel[];
    ...........
fetchTimeIns(){
this.employeesService.getTimeIn()
.subscribe(result=>this.in_timings = result,
error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
 }
  .......................
  ...............

      for(let in_timing of this.in_timings)
  {
      if(in_timing.employee_id===emp_id && in_timing.is_active===true){   

      console.log("You have already checked in!");

    }
     else if((in_timing.employee_id===emp_id && in_timing.is_active===false) || this.in_timings.length<0){

       console.log("Add another row here...");

     }
    else{
      console.log("All conditions exhausted!");
    }
  }
```

In the image, it's showing that the the first statement was executed and the last one was executed twice.

[image]
**I have logged the array of objects to show the structure.**

Comment: what do you expect to happen?

Comment: What i expect is, only one block to execute. What i want is, to be directed how to do that.

Comment: What does _one block to execute_ means?

Comment: what is the behaviour you want to happen. If the current user has an active timing in the list do nothing. If it doesn't have a timing, or has a timing that is not active then do something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I am understanding your problem you want to `break` the execution if any one condition become true. Doing this will make your code to run only one block.

Just add `break` keyword after log.

```
  for(let in_timing of this.in_timings)
  {
  if(in_timing.employee_id===emp_id && in_timing.is_active===true){   

  console.log("You have already checked in!");
   break;

}
 else if((in_timing.employee_id===emp_id && in_timing.is_active===false) || this.in_timings.length<0){

   console.log("Add another row here...");
   break;

 }
else{
  console.log("All conditions exhausted!");
   break;
}
```